# Python 3.6 Bitonic Sort with Multiprocessing library and multiple processes

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to implement bitonic with the python `multiprocessing` library and a shared resource array that will be sorted at the end of the program.

The problem I am running into is that when I run the program, I get an prompt that asks "Your program is still running! Are you sure you want to cancel it?" and then when I click cancel N - 1 times (where N is the amount of processes I am trying to spawn) then it just hangs.

When this is run from the command line, it just outputs the unsorted array. Of course, I expect it to be sorted at the program's finish.

I've been using [this resource](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) to try and get a firm grasp on how I can mitigate my errors but I haven't had any luck, and now I am here.

ANY help would be appreciated, as I really don't have anywhere else to turn to.

I wrote this using Python 3.6 and here is the program in its entirety:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array
import sys
from random import randint

# remember to move this to separate file
def createInputFile(n):
    input_file = open("input.txt","w+")
    input_file.write(str(n)+ "\n")
    for i in range(n):
        input_file.write(str(randint(0, 1000000)) + "\n")

def main():
    # createInputFile(1024) # uncomment this to create 'input.txt'
    fp = open("input.txt","r") # remember to read from sys.argv
    length = int(fp.readline()) # guaranteed to be power of 2 by instructor
    arr = Array('i', range(length)) 
    nums = fp.read().split() 
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        arr[i]= int(nums[i]) # overwrite shared resource values
    num_processes = 8 # remember to read from sys.argv
    process_dict = dict() 
    change_in_bounds = len(arr)//num_processes
    low_b = 0 # lower bound 
    upp_b = change_in_bounds # upper bound 
    for i in range(num_processes): 
        print("Process num: " + str(i)) # are all processes being generated?
        process_dict[i] = Process(target=bitonic_sort, args=(True, arr[low_b:upp_b]) )
        process_dict[i].start()
        low_b += change_in_bounds
        upp_b += change_in_bounds

    for i in range(num_processes):
        process_arr[i].join()

    print(arr[:]) # Print our sorted array (hopefully)

def bitonic_sort(up, x):
    if len(x) <= 1:
        return x
    else: 
        first = bitonic_sort(True, x[:len(x) // 2])
        second = bitonic_sort(False, x[len(x) // 2:])
        return bitonic_merge(up, first + second)

def bitonic_merge(up, x): 
    # assume input x is bitonic, and sorted list is returned 
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x
    else:
        bitonic_compare(up, x)
        first = bitonic_merge(up, x[:len(x) // 2])
        second = bitonic_merge(up, x[len(x) // 2:])
        return first + second

def bitonic_compare(up, x):
    dist = len(x) // 2
    for i in range(dist):  
        if (x[i] > x[i + dist]) == up:
            x[i], x[i + dist] = x[i + dist], x[i] #swap



main()
```

Comment: I chose the `Process` class over the `Pool` class because I felt that the `Process` class was easier to interact with. Is `Pool` the correct approach to these types of problems? And if so, what is the ideal case in which `Process` is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into all the syntax errors in your code since I am sure your IDE tells you about those. The problem that you have is that you are missing an if name==main. I changed your def main() to def sort() and wrote this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sort()
```

And it worked (after solving all the syntax errors)